# Bootstrap tooltip in jsp file...again

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

sorry this again but I couldn't get it work with the existing solutions. This is a .jsp file running in Tomcat 7.

```
<head>
 ...
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-title="tooltip" data-content="hallo" data-placement="right">Tooltip on
                        right</a>
...
```

normally this should work shouldn't it? Already tried to get the .js stuff in the body or end of html file. It's not showing the tooltip. Maybe it is not working in jsp file? oO

Answer (score 1):

Try calling jquery before bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use an input:

```
<input type="text" title="Tooltip on right." data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control tooltip-demo" placeholder="">
```

And his respective script:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
          track: false,
          position: {my: "left+10", at: "right"}
      });
   })
</script>
```